# How can I callback Tcl commands from different namespaces without explicitly qualifying?

Tags: namespaces, callback, eval, tcl, wrapper

Basically the problem is to execute Tcl code defined in one namespace, using calls to functions in that namespace, in an eval inside another namespace.

The following code works fine:

```
namespace eval ::eggs {
    namespace export e1 eeval
    proc e1 {}  { puts pe1 }
    proc eeval body  { puts "in cb enter"; eval $body; puts "in cb exit" }
}
namespace import ::eggs::* 

namespace eval ::spam {
    namespace export s1 scall
    proc scb   {}  { puts pscb }
    proc scall {}  { puts "in call enter"; eeval {::spam::scb}; puts "in call exit" }
    e1
    scall
}
namespace import ::spam::*
```

and prints:

```
% % % % % % pe1
in call enter
in cb enter
pscb
in cb exit
in call exit
```

Now I want to replace the `::spam::scb` with a plain `scb`. I would trade in a wrapper for `eeval`.

My use case:
The namespace `eggs` is a very basic library for regression testing. The namespace `spam` is a small library implementing nice to have functions. They shall be tested upon reload. For this `scall` is called and uses a special test function in `eggs` called `eeval`.

The eeval is the unit test. For convenience and "do-not-repeat-yourself" reasons I'd like to not have to use the fully qualified namespace name of any function defined in `spam`.

Ideally `scall` would look like this:

```
proc scall {}  { puts "in call enter"; eeval {scb}; puts "in call exit" }
```

However, during execution the eval in `::eggs::eeval` does not know where to find `scb`. Since `eggs` is just a test library I cannot import the `spam` namespace.

Is there any way one could e.g. devise a wrapper for e.g. `eeval` to make it run in the other namespace?

Comment: I apologize for choosing stupid names in my example code. I wanted to simplify and abstract/extract the idea, but it would have been more understandable if I had kept the names *sigh* I don't want to edit the Q now that the answers are so good and detailed. When my reputation has grown up I may choose to edit the post and the answers for more clarity...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to pass the code to `eval` (possibly appending arguments) then the simplest method to generate the callback script is with `namespace code`:

```
eeval [namespace code {scb}]
```

That generates all the wrapping code to ensure that things work correctly, including handling all sorts of cases you've not dealt with:

```
% namespace eval boo {
    puts [namespace code {foo bar}]
}
::namespace inscope ::boo {foo bar}
```

However, if you're doing the callback immediately then the most common approach is not the above, but rather to use `uplevel 1` to do the callback:

```
proc eeval body {
    puts "in cb enter"
    uplevel 1 $body
    puts "in cb exit"
}
```

This has the advantage that the called-back code really is in the stack context of the caller, allowing it to do useful things like access local variables. Since the code is running in the same context that you define it<sup>[*]</sup>, it's fine using that for resolving command names.

---

<sup>[*] That's a big fat lie — Tcl's semantics are rather more complex than that — but everything works like what I've said is true.</sup>

Comment: `namespace code` is the functionality I'm looking for, `uplevel` goes one step to far. The caller's code shall be executed in its namespace (by the called namespace) without the risk of accidentally polluting variables. Example would be unittests that are executed by a test harness namespace. Is there any way I can move the `namespace code` functionality into the `::eggs` namespace? Maybe using `inscope` inside `eeval` directly like this: `::namespace inscope [lindex [info level 1] 2] $body`

Comment: @cfi While you could generate the `namespace inscope` yourself, if you're thinking about doing that then I think you're probably trying far too hard. :-) In particular, the fancier the tricks you use, the easier it is to make something very brittle; it's quite difficult to write robust fancy tricks (speaking as someone who's done that more than most…)

Comment: I hear you. Is there any other way? I just love fancy tricks. I'll call back when it breaks (just kidding)

Comment: @cfi: Probably. Can't think of one right now though; it's been a long week…

Answer (score 2):

`namespace current` is the DRYer you're probably looking for.

```
namespace eval ::spam {
    proc scall {}  {
        puts {in call 2 enter}
        eeval [namespace current]::scb
        puts {in call 2 exit}
    }
}
```

Or pass the current namespace to the eeval proc

```
proc ::eggs::eeval {body {namespace ""}} {
    puts "in cb enter"
    if {$namespace == ""} {
        eval $body
    } else {
        namespace eval $namespace $body
    }
    puts "in cb exit"
}

proc ::spam::scall {} {
    puts "in call 3 enter"
    eeval scb [namespace current]
    puts "in call 3 exit"
}
```

Comment: I guess your second suggestion is what I will test tomorrow: I'm looking for a solution where I don't have to pass the namespace in any way. But with your proposal I can curry the call to `eeval` in a wrapper and spice it up with the `$namespace` argument. Wasn't aware of using `namespace eval` in this context, too! Good points. Thanks!

Comment: Your version of `eeval` is close to what I want. I believe there's a way to completely get rid of the `[namespace current]` in `scall` of `::spam`: At the start of `::eggs::eeval` add: `if {$namespace == {}} {
        set namespace [namespace qualifiers [namespace origin [lindex [info level 1] 0]]]
    }`. Then `eeval scb` works, and `eeval { puts [namespace current] }` proves the point. What do you think about it? Could you insert it into your answer?